# How do you write a non-dymanic SQLQuery to only return records that fulfill multiple EXISTS clauses?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the problem I'm running into. I have a query (that works) and what I want it to do is return only records where a user has records for each EXISTS clause. Like this:

```
select * from Users
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM UserSessions
                WHERE UserSessions.UserId = Users.Id
                AND SessionId = 1)
        AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM UserSessions
                WHERE UserSessions.UserId = Users.Id
                AND SessionId = 2)
        AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM UserSessions
                WHERE UserSessions.UserId = Users.Id
                AND SessionId = 3)
```

So in the case specifically, I only want users that have a session Id of 1 AND and session id of 2 AND and session id of 3. This query works but the session id's change and could be 1 or 20 different id's.

Right now I'm dynamically assembling the query as needed (in my server-side app) based on what session id's I need but I'm wondering if there's a way to write this query so I can just pass in the id's and not manually assemble it. Kinda like an `IN` clause but one that'll only return the records where a user appears in all numbers in the `IN` clause.

Every solution I run into seems to be a different version of this current query where I'm having to dynamically assemble the query depending on the session ids needed. Is there any way to make this not so dynamic?

Comment: Use a stored procedure and pass in the Sessions values as parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a reasonable assumption that the keys are unique in a junction/association table such as `UserSessions`.

You can simplify the logic to:

```
select u.*
from Users u join
     (select us.UserId
      from UserSessions us
      where SessionId in (1, 2, 3)   -- your list here
      group by us.UserId
      having count(*) = 3            -- size of the list
     ) us
     on us.UserId = u.Id;
```

You can further parameterize this, depending on how you want to pass in your list.  One method would be parsing a string:

```
with input_sessions as (
      select value as SessionId
      from string_split(@sessions_list, ',')
     )
    select u.*
    from Users u join
         (select us.UserId
          from UserSessions us
          where SessionId in (select sessionId from input_sessions)  
          group by us.UserId
          having count(*) = (select count*) from input_sessions)            
         ) us
         on us.UserId = u.Id;
```

If the keys are not unique, the queries can be tweaked to take this into account.

Comment: Not without assumptions. Here you assume that the tuple <UserId, SessionId) is unique - otherwise your count will include a user with 3 rows that all have the same SessionId.

Comment: @Smor . . . I think that is a reasonable assumption in what appears to be an association/junction table connecting  users and sessions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - this is super helpful and totally answers my question, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 4):

First, create a table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Ints AS TABLE(ID int PRIMARY KEY);
GO
```

You can make that as an argument to your stored procedure (and adjust your server-side code to pass in a DataTable or List as a complex parameter, assuming C# or the like):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetSessionsThatMatchAllIDs
  @IDs dbo.Ints READONLY
AS
...
```

But for now just for testing let's populate it manually:

```
DECLARE @IDs dbo.Ints;
INSERT @IDs VALUES(1),(2),(3); -- ...,(20)

DECLARE @min = COUNT(*) FROM @IDs;

SELECT Id, ... 
  FROM dbo.Users AS u
  WHERE
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SessionID) 
      FROM dbo.UserSessions 
      WHERE UserID = u.ID 
      AND SessionID IN (SELECT ID from @IDs)
  ) = @min;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer; this is super-helpful!!

Comment: Hi Aaron, sorry for hijacking this answer but I really wanted to get your take on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56774937/should-you-use-master-dbo-when-accessing-sp-procedures). I think (perhaps wrongly) that the OP is misunderstanding one of your blog posts - so I think you're the best person to shed some light on the subject.