# Should you use master.dbo when accessing sp_ procedures?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm 100% convinced this is a duplicate but after more than an hour of searching I just can't seem to find the answer.

When using special procedures (i.e. the `sp_` ones like `sp_executesql`), is it wise to use the full 3-part identifier `master.dbo` (or `master..`) or just use them as is?  I'm looking for the most performance optimized version of this:

```
1. sp_executesql
2. master..sp_executesql
3. master.dbo.sp_executesql
```

Are 2 and 3 identical in terms of performance specifically regarding the above (i.e. referencing `master`) and is it safe to user `master..` or should you not risk it even on `master` since someone could still create another schema there at some point?

Much appreciated.

Comment: What results do you see when you test the performance of those three options in your environment?  I personally never use the three-part name for system procedures on the rare occasions when I use them - my performance issues tend to be elsewhere (and by 'elsewhere' I mean 'in my code and/or table structures')

Comment: AFAIK whenever you are executing a stored procedure that starts with the `sp_` prefix SQL Server will first search for it in `master.dbo`, so all three options should have the same performance, but even if not, unless running the stored procedure in a tight loop, I seriously doubt you'll see any noticeable performance difference.

Comment: Personally, I would use `sys.sp_executesql`, not `sp_executesql` or `..` or `.dbo.`... it's a system procedure, make it obvious! Performance is not going to matter (this you can easily test yourself), except maybe in the `..` case where my default schema is something other than `dbo` and *that* schema is checked first), but readability shouldn't be tossed aside in any case.

Comment: Finally, questions that ask "will performance matter if I do this thing that is a very bad idea for other reasons" is kind of silly to be honest.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you for clearing that up. I almost never personally target people on SO with questions (this was the 2nd time ever) but since it was your blog post we discussed I thought no one can explain it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR;**
Shouldn't be any noticeable performance difference.

**The long story:**
Whenever you are executing a stored procedure that starts with the `sp_` prefix SQL Server will first search for it in `master.dbo`, so all three options should have the same performance.

From an article posted by [Eric Cobb](http://www.sqlnuggets.com/about/) in 2015 entitled [Why you should not prefix your stored procedures with “sp_”](http://www.sqlnuggets.com/blog/do-not-prefix-stored-procedures-with-sp_/)

> Whenever SQL Server sees “sp_” at the beginning of a stored procedure, it first tries to find the procedure in the master database.  As stated in the Microsoft documentation above, “This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures“, so when SQL Server sees “sp_” it starts looking for system procedures.  Only after it has searched through all of the procedures in the master database and determined that your procedure is not there will it then come back to your database to try to locate the stored procedure.

Also, it quotes another official documentation (with a link to 2008 version, working on finding current version):

> A user-defined stored procedure that has the same name as a system stored procedure and is either nonqualified or is in the dbo schema will never be executed; the system stored procedure will always execute instead.

That quote, even though I couldn't find in the documentation of current version, I can easily prove.
Consider the following script:

```
USE <YourDatabaseNameHere> -- change to the actual name of the db, of course
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_who
AS
    SELECT 'Zohar peled' as myName
GO

-- change to the actual name of the db, of course
EXEC <YourDatabaseNameHere>.dbo.sp_who
EXEC dbo.sp_who
EXEC sp_who

GO

DROP PROCEDURE  dbo.sp_who  -- cleanup
```

When tested on 2016 version (which is the server I've had available for testing),
All three `exec` statements executed the system procedure. I couldn't find any way to execute my procedure.

Now I can't fiddle around with the `master` DB on my server, so I can only show that it's true for *existing* system procedures, but I'm pretty sure that it's going to be the same for any procedure that starts with the `sp_` prefix, even if you wrote it yourself to both the master database and your own, as Aaron Bertrand illustrated on [his article](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) under the title **Another side effect : Ambiguity**

However, even if that wasn't the case, unless having many procedures in the current schema, and running the stored procedure in a tight loop, I doubt you'll see any *noticeable* performance difference.
Later on in the same article:

> As alluded to in the previous point, procedures named with “sp_” are going to perform slower.  It may not always be noticeable, but it is there.  Connecting to DatabaseA, jumping over to the master database and scanning every stored procedure there, then coming back to DatabaseA and executing the procedure is always going to take more time than just connecting to DatabaseA and executing the procedure.

Note that this paragraph is talking about performance issues executing a user-defined stored procedure that has the `sp_` prefix - so let's reverse this process for a moment:

Suppose SQL Server would have to scan all the stored procedures in the current schema, and only then, if not found, go to `Master.Dbo` and start looking there.
Easy to see the more procedures you have in the schema the longer it takes. However - have you ever noticed how long it takes SQL Server to find the procedure it needs to run? 
I've been working with SQL Server since it's 2000 version, and I've had my share of databases containing hundreds of procedures all cramped up in the same schema - but that was never a performance issue.
In fact, in over 15 years of experience with SQL Server, I've never encountered a performance issue caused by the time it takes SQL Server to find the stored procedure it needs to run.

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems your links are pointing to a different article than the title.  From the article in my post, it shows that sp_ is first searched locally before master which contradicts Eric Cobb's article.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the link. Aaron's article is mentioned as a resource in Cobb's article. I've edited to fix the link and also added another quot you might find interesting:

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think that Aaron's graph proves your point, nor do I think that Cobb got it wrong. In fact, I think that if we could get Aaron to comment or answer on this post, you might be surprised by his answer. I'm pretty interested to read his take on this, and being an active user on Stackoverflow I think he might just give us an answer. I've contacted him and hopefully he'll reply with a comment or answer on this question.